# Issue with IEnumerable and IList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a bit of crisis, I'm fairly new to C#, MVC 3, so this has been hard to get my head around. Basically my view page should output a list of items in the database.

I receive this issue -

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Shipments.Data.shipment_order]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Shipments.Data.DATA]'.

From my controller -

```
public ActionResult Orders()
{
    IList<shipment_order> list = _shipmentSearchService.GetShipmentOrders();
    return View(list);
}
```

From my view, using ASPX also, not razor.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Shipments.Data.DATA>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Orders
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Orders</h2>

<p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            DefaultContainerName
        </th>
        <th>
            CommandTimeout
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DefaultContainerName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommandTimeout) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>

</table>

</asp:Content>
```

I've tried changing `<IEnumerable<Shipments.Data.DATA>>` to `<Shipments.Data.DATA>`. But it just throws a different error, pretty sure I need to use it.

Comment: You are passing collection of `Shipments.Data.shipment_order` to the view, but it's expecting collection of `Shipments.Data.DATA`. Either pass the correct models or change the expecting model type in the view.

Comment: What framework are you using web forms or mvc?

Comment: Zabavsky, thank you for that, that did the trick, changing the view, hopefully I can move on now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error follows your declaration. Your view expects an `IEnumerable<Shipments.Data.DATA>`:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Shipments.Data.DATA>>
```

but your controller gives it an `IList<shipment_order>`:

```
IList<shipment_order> list = _shipmentSearchService.GetShipmentOrders();
```

So the system does what it's supposed to do - instead of doing what you expect from it ;-)...

Answer (score 2):

Change the top part of your view to this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IList<Shipments.Data.DATA>>" %>
```

The key part being:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IList<Shipments.Data.DATA>>
```

In your controller you are passing an object `list` that is a type of `IList<shipment_order>`

In your view you have set the ViewPage to `IEnumerable<shipment_order>`

That is why you were getting that exception, because you can't implicitly convert from a IEnumberable to a IList or vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Try
`List<Shipments.Data.shipment_order>`

Comment: I get an error saying that it cannot implicitly convert it as an explicit one already exists :(